# Remove exact instance of class from list

Tags: c#, list, hashcode

I'm adding a class `Foo` to a `List<Foo>` at some point I want to remove this exact instance of the class from the list I do it this way :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
        Test test = new Test(1);
        int hashCode = test.GetHashCode();
        list.Add(test);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if(list[i].GetHashCode() == hashCode)
            {
                list.Remove(list[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

public class Test
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public Test(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Are there any flaws in my approach ? What's the best way to remove exact instance of object from a list ?

**Edit** forgot to mention :

In my original code I dont keep track of the instance. The class is instantiated in a method where the hashcode is not, so the first one will be forgotten after the method is done. And I'm doing the check otuside the method where the class was instantiated .

Comment: You already have the instance, so just remove it.

Comment: why not just : ``list.Remove(test)``

Comment: An equal hashcode does not guarantee that the objects are equal.

Comment: In my original code I dont keep track of the instance. The class is instantiated in a method where the hashcode is not, so the first one will be forgotten after the method is done. And I'm doing the check otuside the method where the class was instantiated .

Comment: If you don't keep track of the instance, you have no way of knowing which item to remove if there are multiple items with the same `value`. What would you want to do if there are multiple items with, say, `value == 10`? Remove all of them? Remove the first one? Throw an exception? Something else?

Comment: So you don't want to remove *the same istance* after all, since you don't *have* the instance? How do you find the correct instance in the list?

Comment: How about [`object.ReferenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals)?

Comment: OP doesn't have the instance. @Uwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a few.

First, you already have the instance you want to remove. Just do `list.Remove(test)`.

Second, hashcode is not a unique identifier. Two different objects can have the same hashcode - the only thing that must be true is that two identical objects must have the same hashcode and that the hashcode doesn't change. `return 0;` is a perfectly valid implementation of `GetHashCode` (though obviously a bit inefficient :)). Also, `GetHashCode` isn't automatic - your `Test` class doesn't override `GetHashCode`, so you have no idea what it will actually return.

Third, when you remove an item from the middle of a list, all the items after it move. So you need to roll your loop one item back, e.g.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  if (whatever) list.RemoveAt(i--);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, so since your edit made it obvious that you don't know which instance you want to remove, 1) isn't going to work. In any case, 2) still holds - hash code is not a unique identifier. If you need to find an instance based on some value, look for the value, not the hash code.

Comment: @PreqlSusSpermaOhranitel You can't have your cake and eat it too. Either keep the instance around so that you know what to remove, or add *some* kind of identifier to find the right instance. If you can store the hashcode, what's preventing you from remembering the reference?

Comment: I see I was trying to avoid storing the instance, but I guess that's the best way.

Comment: @PreqlSusSpermaOhranitel I wouldn't say it's the *best* way. It just seems like you have no other option available. Why are you trying to avoid storing the instance? How is it different from storing a hash code? Why would it be *worse* than storing a hash code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `list.Remove(test)`. It checks against the equality of the reference of the object, so the exact match will be removed.

[Equal hash codes are not a guarantee for object equality.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) So assuming you will get back the same object using its hash code is wrong. Create an own equality comparer on the list if you need to match the items on other properties than their reference.

Comment: Which one? You can't assume equal hash codes means the same object, so you have to either keep the instance or override `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop need to be in reverse order `for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)` because on removing any element from list , elements will shifted up by 1 position.

Comment: Well, he'd better `break;` if he finds a match.

Comment: Reverse loop is require in case if there are multiple duplicate objects are there. putting `break` will remove only first occurrence. to continue finding more duplicates, loop should go till end. Got my point?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MSDN for GetHashCode, you will see that
-You should not assume that equal hash codes imply object equality.
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx][1]

I would just suggest use

```
list.Remove(test)
```

If the  `public int value { get; set; }` is unique you can use LINQ to remove

```
list.Remove(list.First(t => t.value == 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I want to remove this exact instance of the class from the list

That implies that the the thing you want to remove is an instance of a class, and not a value type. So we know the signature of the function you're looking for is

```
void RemoveExactInstance<A>(List<A> as, A instance) where A : class
```

The remove method on `List` has the remark:

> If type `T` implements the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the equality comparer is the `Equals` method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality comparer is `Object.Equals`.

That means we can't use the `Remove` method.

The same goes for the `IndexOf` method. So iteration and remove the index of the identical object is a valid strategy.

Your implementation uses `GetHashCode` on the instance, but that is not guaranteed to give you a unique hash code; multiple instances can share the same hash code.

What we can do is substitute the hashcode check for a reference equality check. For this we have `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

We can substitute that in your code:

```
void RemoveExactInstance<A>(List<A> as, A instance) where A : class {
    for (int i = as.Count - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(Object.ReferenceEquals(as[i], instance))
        {
            list.Remove(list[i]);
            //if you only want to remove the first instance
            //you want to break; out of the loop here,
            //otherwise, continue on
        }
    }
}
```

edit: in your edit, you say

> In my original code I dont keep track of the instance.

If you don't have the instance, most bets are off. If you only have the hash code, there is no guaranteed way to make this work. So better keep a hold of the instance rather than just the hash code.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question "Remove exact instance in a collection", but it seems you should replace `list.Remove(list[i]);` by `list.RemoveAt(i);`